# how do I display the score on screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a shooter game and want to show the kills on the screen I have a UI with a canvas and text, but I can't get the right number to show on the screen.

this is what I have now:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text Pointsdisplay;
    int points = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        Pointsdisplay.text = points.ToString();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Pointsdisplay.text = points.ToString();
    } 

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {

        if (col.gameObject.name == "enemy(Clone)")
        {
            points = points + 1;
        }
    }

 }
```

I have assigned the right Textobject in unity, but it doesn't seem to be working I get the error message:
`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an      object
Score.Start () (at Assets/Scenes/scripts/Score.cs:12)`
and the same thing with line 17

So in summary: I would like the score on the screen to show how many times I've hit the enemy, but this does not happen. thanks in advance

Comment: Are you ever initializing Pointsdisplay?
If Pointsdisplay = null, you can't set Pointsdisplay.text

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ `Text` is a Unity component, you can't call `new` on it. Janhetjoch needs to either set the reference in the inspector or use a version of `GameObject.Find()`, or spawn a prefab and call `GetComponent` or `AddComponent`

Comment: I've dropped the Text component next to Pointsdisplay in the inspector

Answer (score 0):

Update it only when the value is being updated/changed.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text pointsdisplay;
    int points = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        pointsdisplay.text = points.ToString();
    } 

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "enemy(Clone)")
        {
            points = points + 1;
            pointsdisplay.text = points.ToString();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Although my code now is compacter and therefore looks better it did not solve me problem

Comment: @janhetjoch Problem has nothing to do with your code.